# Javascript onclick function triggers from the second time i click but not the first

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I have this two images that trigger the same function. What the function does is showing/hiding one of the images and then i added some extra code to show/hide a menu, that i haven´t included.

```js
function menu() {
  var b = document.getElementById("burger");
  var c = document.getElementById("close");
  if (b.style.display === "block") {            
      b.style.display = "none";
      c.style.display = "block";
  } else {
      b.style.display = "block";
      c.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="img/burger-white.png" id="burger" onclick="menu()" alt="img1">
<img src="img/close-white.png" id="close" onclick="menu()" alt="img2">
```

Everything works as intended, except for the first time i click on the image, when it does nothing.

Comment: It works on the first click for me. Also, FYI, don't use inline event attributes `onclick` in the first place. Use `.addEventListener()` instead.

Comment: Are #burger or #close meant to be visible when the page loads?

Comment: @holaymolay Only when the screen width is smaller than 1100px

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the display for burger is not initially set to block. Try loading the page and inspect it with chrome. There you should see, when the page is loaded, if it initially have the expected css style.

A workaround, would be to add a function that will set the display of the element with id #burger to "block", if the window size is less that a 1100px.

```
function setDisplay() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var b = document.getElementById("burger");
    if(width <= 1100) {
        b.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: I added an explicit rule about it being display:block; in a css file, but it´s added to trigger when the screen width is smaller than 1100px, that is the maximum resolution in which the menu shows. But it does not respond the first time i click

Comment: Then it should be working, since the script is correct. Can I see the css @media rule you are using?

Comment: @media all and (max-width: 1100px){
#burger{display:block;}
}

Comment: Weird, everything seems right. A workaround, would be to add a function that will run when the page is loaded. This function will set the burger.style.display to "block", only if the window size if less than 1100px. I will add this function to my answer.

Comment: The solution was to add an inline style code setting the element to block, as doing it from the css file did not work.